# How could we express the space in an other way?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to calculate a triple integral over the space $$D=\{(x,y,z)\mid |x|\leq 1, |y|\leq 1, z\geq 0, x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\}$$

$$$$

We have the following:

- $|x|\leq 1\Rightarrow -1\leq x\leq 1$
- $|y|\leq 1\Rightarrow -1\leq y\leq 1$
- $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1 \Rightarrow z^2\leq 1-x^2-y^2\Rightarrow -\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$, since $z\geq 0$ we get $0 \leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$.

  So that the square root is defined it must hold that $1-x^2-y^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow x^2+y^2\leq 1 \Rightarrow x^2\leq 1-y^2 \Rightarrow -\sqrt{1-y^2}\leq x\leq \sqrt{1-y^2}$, right?

So, how could we express $D$ in an other way?

$$D=\{(x,y,z)\mid -1\leq x\leq 1, -1\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\}$$ or $$D=\{(x,y,z)\mid -\sqrt{1-y^2}\leq x\leq \sqrt{1-y^2}, -1\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\}$$ ?

Comment: What is the integral that you have to evaluate? Note that $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$ implies  $|x|\leq 1, |y|\leq 1$.

Comment: I want to calculate the integral $\iiint_D z dxdydz$. So, is the first one correct, i.e. $D=\{(x,y,z)\mid -1\leq x\leq 1, -1\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\}$ ? Why does $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$ imply $|x|\leq 1, |y|\leq 1$ ? Do we not solve the inequality for $z$ : $z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ ? @RobertZ

Comment: But when we write $D$ in that form, can it not be that $x=y=1$ ? Then we have that $z\leq \sqrt{1-1^2-1^2}=\sqrt{-1}$, or not? @RobertZ

Comment: That's right, in fact the point $(1,1)$ is not in $D$.

Comment: But writing $D$ in the form $\{(x,y,z)\mid -1\leq x\leq 1, -1\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\}$ do we know that this point is not contained? @RobertZ

Comment: Yes because the argument of the square root should be non-negative.

Comment: Ah ok! But why is it wrong to use the other expression of $D$ ? Does it not describe the same set? Or do we loose some points with this description? @RobertZ

Comment: Your last expression of $D$ is correct. You may use it, but it is more convenient to make a change of variables.

Comment: I mean why we can't use the expression $\{(x,y,z)\mid -\sqrt{1-y^2}\leq x\leq \sqrt{1-y^2}, -1\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\}$ ? Does this set not describe the same points as $\{(x,y,z)\mid -1\leq x\leq 1, -1\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\}$ ? @RobertZ

Comment: YES. See my edited answer.

Comment: Using the set $\{(x,y,z)\mid -1\leq x\leq 1, -1\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\}$ we get that the integral is equal to $\frac{2}{3}$ [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_(-1)%5E1(int_(-1)%5E(1)(int_0%5E(sqrt(1-x%5E2-y%5E2))zdz)dx)dy ] and using the set $\{(x,y,z)\mid -\sqrt{1-y^2}\leq x\leq \sqrt{1-y^2}, -1\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\}$ we get the result $\frac{\pi}{4}$ [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_(-1)%5E1(int_(-sqrt(1-y%5E2))%5E(sqrt(1-y%5E2))(int_0%5E(sqrt(1-x%5E2-y%5E2))zdz)dx)dy] @RobertZ

Comment: Using the cylindrical or the spherical  coordinates as in your answer we get $\frac{\pi}{4}$. So, I have to use the expression $\{(x,y,z)\mid -\sqrt{1-y^2}\leq x\leq \sqrt{1-y^2}, -1\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\}$ for $D$, or not? @RobertZ

Comment: I looked now in the solutions... According to that the answer should be $\frac{2}{3}$. So is the given solution wrong? @RobertZ

Comment: The evaluation is correct. If you use the cylindrical or the spherical coordinates you don't need that expression of $D$.

Comment: Please check the statement for the problem. Where does this exercise come from?

Comment: The professor gave this exercise. I have to use cartesian coordinates. So, which expression of $D$ is correct? I got stuck right now. @RobertZ

Comment: The last one $\{(x,y,z)\mid -\sqrt{1-y^2}\leq x\leq \sqrt{1-y^2}, -1\leq y\leq 1, 0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\}$ is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$ implies  $|x|\leq 1, |y|\leq 1$: 
$$|x|^2=x^2\leq x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1 \implies |x|\leq 1.$$
Hence, $D$ is the upper-half unit ball centered at the origin
$$D=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\;:\; z\geq 0, x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1\}.$$

By using the [cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system), we have (see your last line)
$$\iiint_D f(x,y,z)\, dxdydz =\int_{y=-1}^1\int_{x=-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\int_{z=0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} f(x,y,z)\, dxdydz.$$

By using the [cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system), we get
$$\iiint_D f(x,y,z)\, dxdydz =\int_{z=0}^1\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\rho=0}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}} f(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta,z) \rho d\rho  d\theta dz.$$

By using the [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates), we get
$$\iiint_D f(x,y,z)\, dxdydz \\=\int_{\rho=0}^1\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\varphi=0}^{\pi/2} f(\rho\sin \varphi\cos\theta,\rho\sin \varphi\sin\theta,\rho\cos \varphi) \rho^2\sin(\varphi)d\rho d\varphi d\theta.$$